# why i can't get the actual length of this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function getItems() {

  var item=document.getElementById('itemName').value;
  var items=[];
  var split = item.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  items.push(split);
  console.log(items.length);
}
```

I want to get the length of the array, when i run this code i only get '1' as the length.

Answer (score 2):

The array only has one item in it: The result of the `match` call, which you pushed onto the array.

If your goal was to *set* `items` to the result of the match, you'd assign to `items` rather than using `push`. You also wouldn't create an array to start with, since `match` gives you one:

```
var items = item.match(/\s+\s*/g);
console.log(items.length);
```

Example:

```js
function getItems() {

  var item=document.getElementById('itemName').value;
  var items = item.match(/\S+\s*/g);
  console.log(items.length);
}
getItems();
```

```html
<input id="itemName" value="one two three">
```

---

Side note: Your results will include the whitespace after each series of non-whitespace characters. If that's what you want, great; if not, you could look at `split`:

```
var items = item.split(/\s+/);
```

But it depends on what you want in `items` as an end result.